# Collapsing Columns in R using tidyverse with mutate, replace, and unite. Writing a function to reuse?

Tags: r, dplyr

Data:

| ID | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | x |
| 2 | x | NA |
| 3 | x | x |

Results:

| ID | Unified |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B_C |

I'm trying to combine colums B and C, using mutate and unify, but how would I scale up this function so that I can reuse this for multiple columns (think 100+), instead of having to write out the variables each time? Or is there a function that's already built in to do this?

My current solution is this:

```
library(tidyverse)

Data %>% 
mutate(B = replace(B, B == 'x', 'B'), C = replace(C, C == 'x', 'C')) %>%
unite("Unified", B:C, na.rm = TRUE, remove= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `across` to loop over the column, `replace` the value that corresponds to 'x' with column name (`cur_column()`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Data %>%
    mutate(across(B:C, ~ replace(., .== 'x', cur_column()))) %>%
    unite(Unified, B:C, na.rm = TRUE, remove = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 ID Unified
1  1       C
2  2       B
3  3     B_C
```

#### data

```
Data <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, B = c(NA, "x", "x"), C = c("x", NA, 
"x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of options.

1. Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- names(Data)[-1]

Data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Unified = paste0(cols[!is.na(c_across(B:C))], collapse = '_')) %>%
  ungroup -> Data

Data

#     ID B     C     Unified
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#1     1 NA    x     C      
#2     2 x     NA    B      
#3     3 x     x     B_C
```

2. Base R

```
Data$Unified <- apply(Data[cols], 1, function(x) 
                      paste0(cols[!is.na(x)], collapse = '_'))
```